# How can i fix this sql query link issue?

Tags: php, hyperlink

```
echo '<td><a href="takimlar.php?mid=' . $row[0] . '"$ >' . $row[0] .'-)'.  $row[1] .'</a></td>';

"4-)2014-08-29"
```

It seems like this with a link, but I want to no link on id number, just on date and still id number side by side of date in a row.

Thanks for answers.

Comment: Could it be, that there is something missing? I don't understand anything...

Comment: Hard to conclude what you want to achieve

Comment: Can anybody make any sense out of the question!!! :P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

However it is difficult to understand your question but I think you want this :

```
echo '<td>' . $row[0] .'-) <a href="takimlar.php?mid=' . $row[0] . '"$ >'.  $row[1] .'</a></td>';
```

Comment: @GeorgeGarchagudashvili now people will understand the question thanks for your edit :P hope OP mean the same

Comment: Ahh my bad english sorry about it. Thanks currently its working as i want.

Comment: @eremir NP glad it helped you